# Ito's Lemma (Distribution of $S_t)$

Tags: stochastic-calculus

If I am given that $$dS_t=S_t(\mu dt+\sigma dZ_t)$$

How do I find the distribution of $S_t$ by using Ito's Lemma? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the stochastic differential equation for *geometric brownian motion*. Search online for something like "Ito's lemma geometric brownian motion". For instance, see SRKX's answer at https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/what-is-itos-lemma-used-for-in-quantitative-finance.

Comment: Thanks for your help! @MinusOne-Twelfth

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, it might be worth applying Ito's Lemma to $d(ln(S_t))$ (which should give you $(\mu −\frac{1}{2}σ^2)dt + σdW_t$).